# We are not getting price and images urls catalogProductAttributeMediaList and catalogProductGetSpecialPrice in magento soap api calls?

Tags: soap, magento-1.9

We are getting neither price nor image urls from magento soap api calls  catalogProductAttributeMediaList and catalogProductGetSpecialPrice.

can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

when requesting *catalogProductAttributeMediaList* you will get array of stdObject's with following properties:

- file
- label
- position
- exclude
- url
- types

if not, please post your api response to get further advice

Comment: How to check?  can you tell me

Comment: i have no idea from where and how you are consuming Magento api. You may use Soap UI to test your responses outside of code.